# Cloud search settings not found

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create custom google cloud search using the following document:

[G Suite Admin Help - Create a Custom Search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9043922?hl=en&ref_topic=7056075)

For some reason, the Search settings under Cloud Search are not appearing

[Cloud Search settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCULv.png)

The help documentation indicates gsuite enterprise is required. The account  used is indeed enterprise with super admin access. It is unclear however if a service account is required.

[Accounts - Admin roles & privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1FbU.png)

If this documentation is correct, the cloud search settings in the admin console should show the datasource/ApplicationID settings. Are the support docs outdated?

[Documentation - Create a search application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1LY.png)

The sample project for creating a cloud search interface using the default datasource throws a 403 permissions error for any query to the API. I suspect this may be related to the same underlying issue. 
[GsuiteDevs Cloud Seach Sample on Github](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/cloud-search-samples/issues/1)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that support for this feature  is limited to select customers.

https://gsuite.google.com/products/cloud-search/
We are expanding Cloud Search to support third-party content repositories with a first wave of customers.